# Tinymce 5 dialog urlinput disable/enable broken

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

Heads up to anyone who is self hosting who also runs across this bug....

In version 5.6.0 silver theme, the dialog urlinput enable/disable works for the input field but not the browse button of the control.  The problem is that the enable/disable events are intercepted by the typeaheadBehaviours portion of the internal object so they never make it to the event handlers for the overall field.  The fix is to add the onDisabled and onEnabled handlers to the Disabling.config for typeaheadBehaviours and remove the line of code from each handler that addresses the input field.

Original typeaheadBehaviours  Disabling.config....

```
Disabling.config({
  disabled: function () {
    return spec.disabled || providersBackstage.isDisabled();
  }
})
```

Amended code....

```
Disabling.config({
  disabled: function () {
    return spec.disabled || providersBackstage.isDisabled();
  },
  onDisabled: function (comp) {
    memUrlPickerButton.getOpt(comp).each(Disabling.disable);
  },
  onEnabled: function (comp) {
    memUrlPickerButton.getOpt(comp).each(Disabling.enable);
  }
})
```

Haven't been able to figure out how to get those events to bubble up to the the overall control handlers but this seems to make things work as expected.

Comment: Is there a question or a problem besides the bug which should be solved in the project's issue tracker?

Comment: No question, just putting this out there for others to find when searching about the issue.